# xattrs patch for tar-1.23 version(GNU tar)

Tags: attributes, tar

xattrs patch for tar-1.23 version(GNU tar).

I am working on a project which requires xattr support(along with capabilities)of GNU tar-1.23 version.I am unable to get these extended attributes by GNU tar 1.23(from opensource www.gnu.org package).I found that fedora and centos GNU tar-1.23 version has option --with-xattrs ,I am new to this ,so please help me to resolve this problem in tar-1.23 version.Please provide me the patch file for tar-1.23 supports xattrs or the source from which I can get the same.

Thanks in advance